# tpm2 tools fail because /dev/tpm0 missing although the tpm server is running

Tags: simulator, tpm

I'm following [this guide to use tpm2.0 simulator](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/wiki/Getting-Started).

This is my situation:

Firstly, I ran:

```
$ ./tpm_server 
TPM command server listening on port 2321
Platform server listening on port 2322
```

Then, I opened a new terminal and ran:

```
sudo tpm2-abrmd --allow-root --tcti=mssim
```

Nothing happened but in the previous terminal, there were:

```
$ ./tpm_server 
TPM command server listening on port 2321
Platform server listening on port 2322
Command IPv6 client accepted
Platform IPv6 client accepted
```

I opened a new terminal more and ran command as the guide showed and there was some errors:

```
$ tpm2_pcrlist 
ERROR:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tcti-device.c:319:Tss2_Tcti_Device_Init() Failed to open device file /dev/tpm0: No such file or directory 
ERROR: tcti init allocation routine failed for library: "device" options: "(null)"
ERROR: Could not load tcti, got: "device"
```

How should I do to fix it?

Comment: You can try `TSS2_LOG=tcti+TRACE tpm2_pcrlist` to get more output, as explained here: https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss/blob/master/doc/logging.md

Answer (score 0):

I got some error like you while running tpm2 command as you did.

You could try to run with "sudo". it works for me.